# block Certificate authority server

Tags: ssl, certificate, certificate-authority

is this possible to block a specific TLS CA(certificate authority) on network ?
for example block all certs that is issued by letsencrypt on my network
is there any ip or host name for blocking ?

Comment: You can remove its CA certificate from your computer. How you do that depends on operating system and browser.

Comment: That really depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. Do you want to stop trusting certificates issued by that CA? Or do you want to prevent a particular CA from issuing certificates for your systems?

Comment: I know that , but I want block it on main network

Comment: I want just block letsencrypt CA root server in main network

Comment: It is per-machine configuration. You have to configure each machine to distrust the CA certificate. If possible, you should automate the process by using means provided by your operating system. But this is not a complete solution. Some software (like FireFox browser) use their own root certificate store, so you will need to reconfigure these applications too.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to block letsencrypt certs from being issued for your domain, or are you trying to block trusting of any letsencrypt signed certs?

Comment: Imagine I have a server with 10 virtual vps run on it , I want to block any request to letsencrypt to prevent validate certs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't block certificates issued by a CA by blocking specific ip-addresses or hostnames in your firewall.

Once a certificate has been issued neither the service using the certificate, nor the client accessing that service needs contact with the CA to be able to use the certificate to secure communications.

(That is a simplification: for instance checking the revocation status of certificate does need contact with the CA, but AFAIK usually when revocation status can't be checked, the certificate is assumed to be valid.)

Comment: that is mean the CA is hard coded in OS ?

Comment: @neb Yes, in the OS and sometimes in the web browser. Which I advised you several hours ago.

Comment: Revocation checking can also be done without the CA if using a 3rd-party CRL repository or OCSP responder (Chrome kind of does the former) or OCSP stapling (now fairly common).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to block letsencrypt (or any CA) issuing for you domain and you control your own DNS, then publish a CAA record within your domain.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization

So if you want to block all CAs you could add a record like

```
example.com.    IN      CAA     0 issue ";"
```

> Imagine I have a server with 10 virtual vps run on it , I want to block any request to letsencrypt to prevent validate certs

If you are running all the web servers server you could block the HTTP-01 challenge by adjusting your web server to block access to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` location.  If you have reverse proxy or web filter in place on incoming traffic you could also block these URLs there.